# How to replace foreach with linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    item.category = "All Items";
}
```

How to replace the above foreach with Linq.

I have tried with following code, but it returns null for the item

```
_ = items.Select(x => x.item = "All Items")
```

Note : `items` is of type `IEnumerable<ItemList>`

Comment: `items.ForEach(item => item.category = "All Items");`

Comment: @NasirIslamSujan - thats not LINQ, its a method of Array

Comment: LINQ is for querying data, not transforming data. Just use `foreach` - that is what it is for.

Answer (score 0):

linq is an example of functional programming - in general it does not change the input data it reads it in  and outputs new data

you can do this (assuming you have a List to start with)

```
 items = items.Select(item=>new {category="All Items", x=.., y=..}).ToList()
```

wher x and y are the other fields in ItemList

Comment: You shouldn't be using side effects in `Select` in LINQ.

Comment: @NetMage - what side effect?

Comment: `item.category = "All Items"` uses the assignment operator to modify the value in `item.category`. That is a side effect.

Comment: @NetMage - you are quite correct - this is a garbage answer. Will fix